# protocol stack of a blockchain-based network?

Tags: blockchain, iot

I am newbie to block chain. AFAIK, blockchain is a distributed database that maintains a continuously-growing list of records called blocks secured from tampering and revision.

How to explain blockchain in terms of OSI 7-layer model? Is it based on service in the application layer?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer in terms of Bitcoin (the first and main blockchain application) to keep things simple and provide a specific context.

The simple answer is that Bitcoin is an application, so layer 7. Bitcoin Core, the main implementation of the protocol uses TCP, but this is not necessarily required. It could use it's own protocol. All that matters is that any application that participates in the distributed application called Bitcoin agrees on the consensus rules (e.g. block validation rules, transaction validity, etc). Indeed other implementations of Bitcoin other than Bitcoin Core exist and are in use (e.g. [libbitcoin](https://libbitcoin.dyne.org/index.html)).

In terms of OSI model, Bitcoin doesn't really need to affect any of the other layers, except to improve efficiency. Also, the OSI model only refers to the networking used in the blockchain, but while Bitcoin uses networking to enable the application, it is far more than a distributed network. It is the first application to use a reliable consensus protocol for agreeing on the state of a distributed application.

[image: OSI model]

### Notes

Even the physical layers have been affected, for example:

- [Blockstream](https://blockstream.com/satellite/) has enabled Bitcoin over satellite transmission to enable access to users around the world without a DSL/Cable connection.
- Bitcoin uses specialized hardware. Miners are specialized hardware, containing ASICs (Application Specific Integrated Circuits) that are optimized to convert energy (electricity) to SHA256 hashes per second (the hashing function used in mining). This hardware gets and sends data back and forth from the main Bitcoin application in order to perform it's mining function.

Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83410/blockchain-and-iso-osi